# Jquery Chosen não retornando valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, script

Como fazer para que o **chosen** exibao valor da busca. Não esta mostrando as opções dentro do select.

**HTML**

```
<select id="habilidades" name="habilidades[]" multiple class="input col-lg-10 chosen-select margem20" required>

</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$("#subcategoria").change(function(){

            $.post("inc_habilidades.php",
                {id:$(this).val()},
                function(valor2){
                    $("#habilidades").html(valor2)
                }
            )
        })

        $(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

O retorno do arquivo **inc_habilidades.php**, não estão aparecendo dentro do select

Comment: Em seu código não esta sendo mostrado o componente que **#subcategoria**... onde ele está?

Comment: @NayronMorais **#subcategoria** esta acima. Ao selecionar ele esta passando o POST corretamente para o arquivo `inc_habilidades.php`, antes eu testei por `GET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando `$.post` assíncrono, você pode colocar `$(".chosen-select").chosen();` dentro da função.

Exemplo:

```
$("#subcategoria").change(function(){

        $.post("inc_habilidades.php",
            {id:$(this).val()},
            function(valor2){
                $("#habilidades").html(valor2)
                $(".chosen-select").chosen();
            }
        )
    })
```